# Symfony2 : How to make a form with a ManyToMany relationship with fields?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

Here are my entities :

```
/**
 * Message_User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="message_user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Message_User
{    
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Learnpack\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="mu")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Learnpack\MessageBundle\Entity\Message", inversedBy="mu")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="message_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $message;

/**
 * @var string $status
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=45)
 */
private $status;
}


    /**
 * Message
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="message")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Message
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="subject", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $subject;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=45)
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="send", type="datetime")
 */
private $send;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modified", type="datetime")
 */
private $modified;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Learnpack\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $sender;
```

Now I would like to make a form with basic message sending. There will be three fields:

Recipient, subject and content.

My problem is that I do not know how to add a field "input" with ajax for the recipient.